# How to reset array in C

Tags: c, arrays, reset

```
cards[] = {2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4, 4, 5, 5, 5, 5, 6, 6, 6, 6, 7, 7, 7, 7, 8, 8, 8, 8, 9, 9, 9, 9, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 11, 11, 11, 11};
```

I have this array for my game, and when I have used a number in my array, it will be replaced with 0. After the game I need to reset the array, otherwise 0's will stay in array.

How can I reset that array?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make an array which has the original values stored. When you want to reset it, copy it to the original string:

```
int temp_cards[] = {2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4, 4, 5, 5, 5, 5, 6, 6, 6, 6, 7, 7, 7, 7, 8, 8, 8, 8, 9, 9, 9, 9, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 11, 11, 11, 11};
int cards[] = {2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4, 4, 5, 5, 5, 5, 6, 6, 6, 6, 7, 7, 7, 7, 8, 8, 8, 8, 9, 9, 9, 9, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 11, 11, 11, 11};
...
memcpy( cards, init_cards, sizeof cards );    // copying temp_card to card and resetting card
```

`memcpy` is recommended, but if you want to keep it simple you can also copy one string to another using `=`.

---

Another method which @Dandorid suggested is good, just I will provide you how to do it :

```
void reset (int *cards) {
    int temp_cards[] = {2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4, 4, 5, 5, 5, 5, 6, 6, 6, 6, 7, 7, 7, 7, 8, 8, 8, 8, 9, 9, 9, 9, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 11, 11, 11, 11};
    memcpy (cards, temp_cards, sizeof (cards));
}
```

An when you call it, pass the `cards` array.

Answer (score 1):

Define one array for init values and other for working values:

```
const int init_cards[] = {2,2,2,2,3,3...};
int cards[sizeof init_cards / sizeof init_cards[0]];

...
memcpy( cards, init_cards, sizeof cards );  // reset values
```

To reset - copy `init_cards` to `cards`.

Comment: Just add a `const` in front of `init_cards` to avoid modification.

Answer (score 1):

Create a function that initializes your array; then call it at the start of each game.

Answer (score 0):

Have two arrays: One with the default settings and one which you modify. When "resetting" copy from the default array to the array you modify.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a function, say `Initialize`, that uses `memcopy` (or a manually coded loop) to fill the array with some predifined values; there is no way to restore some initial state to the array.

Answer (score 0):

You can't. You need to make an array you won't change and copy it to the working array. Repeat the copy as required.